# IIS URL-Rewrite: HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: iis, https, url-rewriting, url-routing, url-rewrite-module

I have some site `example.org`, on which I keep subsites like `example.com/project1` and `example.com/project2` and so on. I need simple `HTTP→HTTPS` redirect on some of subsites only, but don't want to write it in codefiles manually.

So I found `URL-Rewrite2` module and rule for him:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
```

It works at most with one problem: it redirects from `http://example.com/project1` to `https://example.com/`, so it lost's subsite URL part and any args.

How this can be fixed?

UPD: used this rule

```
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="(.*)" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{UNENCODED_URL}" />
</rule>
```

Subsite redirects normally except that arguments is duplicating. `http://example.com/project1?page=2` turns into `https://example.com/project1?page=2&page=2`. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done using this rule:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{UNENCODED_URL}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Works good on subsites.

Answer (score 0):

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect to http" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" negate="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
```

add that to the system.webserver section